# Is there a way to get about a 10ns Timer resolution from an AVR CPU?

Tags: programming, arduino-ide, timers, atmega32u4, oscillator-clock

I have an 8Mhz ATM32u4 that is able to read external pulse inputs at 125ns ticks using InputCapture3 (PC7) on its 16-bit timer.  Is there a magical way (bitbanging?) to get around 10ns tick resolution to read pulses?  Edit:  like ADC conversions to allow 16-bit systems 24-bit accuracy via creative coding, etc.

If there is no magic, I should use a faster CPU?  I am limited in coding pretty much to AVR type CPUs in the Arduino IDE.  So wondering what AVR CPU would be fast enough for a 10ns tick that is incorporated already into like a Nano, UNO, etc?

Unless I am able to use Pin Interrupts that are able to read at 10ns intervals, then I could use ARM CPU types with Arduino IDE code which does not require me to dive deep into register level language.

Or, is there a stand-alone analog or digital IC that is able to read at 10ns intervals pulses that an Arduino can process?

Thank you.

Edit:  I would need to measure the length of a one-shot pulse only, not a continuous or changing signal. Down to 70us length with an accuracy of at least 18ns tick, but preferably 10ns to account for hardware, etc inaccuracies. This one-shot pulse could repeat not more frequently then 1 second apart, but likely several seconds apart. The signal is two positive square waves forming a pulse measuring not less than 70us from the positive rising edge to rising edge. The system measures the pulse length and sends it the user (serial, BLE, etc).

Edit 2: someone suggested a "one-shot pulse stretcher". Interesting concept...   The more I am looking into it, the more I think it's a very viable hardware solution to the AVR's processing speed limitation. One may say that this is hardware "bitbanging" by streching out the short pulse to a proportionally longer one that the MCU capture process can measure reliably/accurately. An example is this old IC from Linear Tech. See Fig 12 and Fig 13.    https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6752fc.pdf

http://www.anderswallin.net/2014/02/pulse-stretcher-v1/
[image]

[image]

The shortest expected pulse would be about 70us which needs to be measured at (around) a resolution of 18ns for the accuracy I need.  So I went with 10ns for design to allow for some accuracy "overhead".  That is between 4000-7000 counts/ticks  (18ns-10ns ticks) for the 70us signal.

If I stretch this same 70us signal to be measured with the pulse-stretcher to 700us and use the currently available 125ns tick interval of the ATM32u4, I should arrive in theory to about the same accuracy as using an 18ns tick for a 70us signal to be measured.

Here is a similar problem that was answered: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/46922/lengthening-a-5-ns-pulse

Comment: You have a clock and it only ticks once per hour.  What bits are you going to bang that will let you measure seconds with that clock?  Same problem with the micro.  The smallest unit of time it knows is 125ns for an 8MHz clock.  There is nothing smaller than that.

Comment: What exactly is it that you think "bitbanging" means?  Or is it just a term you heard?

Comment: you are talking about a 100 MHz event ... how often does the event occur?

Comment: jsotola   It is a one shot pulse that can happen not less than in 1 second intervals, but can happen several seconds apart.

Comment: Delta_G   yes, I heard the term "bitbanging" (in general) when hardware does not cut the mustard and "creative" software methods are used to extrapolate the data to achieve accuracy/resolution that cannot be achieved with the given hardware. Could you describe it in a way that would correct my faulty understanding?

Comment: Delta_G could you address the other parts of my question which was not related to "bitbanging", which identify completely different potential solutions? Thank you for your constructive assistance!  What makes this forum great is to hear suggestions from folks like you who are willing spend time on a positive guidance focused on the correct portions of one's questions while also pointing out the incorrect ones..

Comment: Do you need to “capture” a 10ns event that occurs at most once per second? It’s unclear what you need to do with these events. Do you need to measure the amount of time between events? Do you need to react to such an event? With some external (TTL or dedicated I2C/SPI) timer components you could build an external timer that’s capable of doing this.

Comment: There are some Arduino-compatible boards based on the ATtiny85. This has a fast asynchronous timer that can be clocked off a PLL at 64 MHz. It's probably the fastest you can get on an AVR, but it doesn't have an input capture unit.

Comment: Do you need to measure the length or the pulse, or just it's existence? If you latter you'd need to stretch this 10ns pulse to something longer that 125ns. Something like an RC filter.

Comment: @ Edgar Bonet thank you for the excellent suggestion.  It's a great feature to get a 64Mhz timer from an 8 MHz internal RC clock by using an 8x scaled software solution!  That would get me to 15.625 ns, which could work if all theoretical cals are accurate in real life hardware.   I looked into it. It requires some pin mapping to Timer1 as the 64 Mhz clock after enabling the PLL,  but then would still need to setup a counter etc. and unfortunately due to my limited knowledge in coding at the registry level I rather not proceed that way.  .

Comment: @ StarCat and Gerben. I would need to measure the length of a one-shot pulse only, not a continuous or changing signal.  Down to 70us length with an accuracy of at least 18ns tick, but preferably 10ns to account for hardware, etc inaccuracies.  This one-shot pulse could repeat not more frequently then 1 second apart, but likely several seconds apart. The signal is two positive square waves forming a pulse measuring not less than 70us from the positive rising edge to rising edge. The system measures the pulse length and sends it the user (serial, BLE, etc).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add information. I spent several minutes to find the relevant stuff down here, and I did this just for curiosity. Most others will not do it.

Comment: someone suggested a "pulse stretcher". Interesting concept...  http://www.anderswallin.net/2014/02/pulse-stretcher-v1/

Comment: @the busybee   At first I was a bit "annoyed" at your comment, but I did fix it immediately.  Now that I have gone back and edited, I want to thank you for pointing out that important changes/updates need to go up in the main post. It certainly made my review/progress easier and I am sure it also serves the same for other readers.  At the end it helps me by helping others better help me.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing you can do on the AVR processors that I know of, which can run on from a quite slow clock, and I think up to 24 MHz. Since your Uno / Leonardo / Micro run at 16 MHz that would be only an incremental speed improvement (to clock them at 24 MHz).

Your idea of bit-banging is interesting, but in general bit-banging is a last resort when you need extra things the hardware doesn't provide (like an extra SPI port) and in general will be slower, not faster, because it involves code rather than inbuilt hardware.

Running at 16 MHz each clock pulse is 62.5 ns which means that is the absolute most resolution it could count. I don't see why you can't count at the rate of 62.5 ns (rather than 125 ns), however that isn't 10 ns resolution.

> Or, is there a stand-alone analog or digital IC that is able to read at 10ns intervals pulses that an Arduino can process?

Very likely. There are probably dedicated counting chips that would do that for you. I haven't looked, but it is the sort of thing there would be a market for. Such a chip would probably use I2C or SPI to communicate, which is easy enough to interface to.

Comment: Mr. Gammon. Really appreciate your input. I've been studying your website's Microprocessor guides/examples & incorporated them into various projects.They are very clear & cover exhaustively the topic for people like me that are not that experienced. Thank you very much for that, sincerely. So based on your and the other comments above, including Edgar Bonet's, the closet one for an AVR is an Atiny85 with an internal oscillator scaled 8x to 64 MHz via PLL that theoretically can give 15.625 ns ticks for a timer that needs to be set up, etc but beyond my skills. Will look for faster non-AVR CPUs.

Comment: Mr. Gammon  If I may have the audacity to ask you two related questions? #1: reference the 328p and 32u4 using the InputCaptureCounter/Timer (16-bit) and implementing an external pulse-read (like in your #12 reply example under "Timers").  You used an ISR timer/counter and an ISR for overflow. Comparing that with using attachInterrupt based pulse-read on the INT0/1 pin(s) and accounting for the time it take to enter/leave the ISR (@5us), would both solutions have the same inherent accuracy?

Comment: Mr. Gammon   This is the #2 related question: I combined your InputCaptureCounter/Timer example and your CPU Deep Sleep example for the 328p (using the 32u4).  That is the code that I was hoping to "beef up" to read 70us pulses at 10ns resolution and is located here: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/77978/input-capture-with-sleep-enabled-on-atm32u4-board-only-works-every-second-readin/77981#77981

Comment: Perhaps if you explain in more detail your project? Why do you need to measure such short pulses?

Comment: Mr. Gammon  Someone suggested a "one-shot pulse stretcher". Interesting concept...   The more I am looking into it, the more I think it's a very viable hardware solution to the AVR's processing speed limitation. One may say that this is hardware "bitbanging" by streching out the short pulse (via an RC "timer") to a proportionally longer one that the MCU capture process can measure reliably/accurately. Only requires three extra components. An example is this old LTC6752 from Linear Tech. See Fig 12 and Fig 13.    https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/6752fc.pdf

Comment: If you make this work I suggest you post your own answer to your question, giving details about how you did it, for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: Mr. Gammon   I will do.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

1 ns is a billionth of a second. A 1 gHz clock has a cycle time of 1 ns. If you have a timer that's able to count single clock pulses you'd need a 1 gHz clock to get to 1 ns resolution. for 10 ns, you'd need a 100 mHz clock.

You won't get close to 10 ns resolution with an 8 mHz clocked device.

Comment: Duncan C, thank you for breaking it down to the numbers.  Yes, clearly would need an MCU with a faster input capture/timer, or a dedicated external IC that can do the same.  Wondering, if a fast ADC would do?  I suspect that Freq-to-Volt converter would be too inaccurate at these periods. And using a Freq dow-counter by 10 or 12 for example is would not work with a single-shot pulse that is only 70us in length/period,

Comment: 10 ns is a very short duration. No way would you use something like frequency to voltage to measure durations that short.